# Changes to nfc apdu for emv visa paywave cards?

Tags: nfc, apdu, emv

I am trying to send APDUs to EMV cards to retrieve information through Android nfc. I am able to retrieve information thru selecting applet AID, getting PDOL and sending read commands for older cards.

**APDU for selecting applet:**

```
00 A4 04 00 07 AID 00
```

**GET PROCESSING OPTIONS:**

```
80 A8 00 00 12 83 10 B6 20 C0 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 82 3D DE 7A 01 24 00
```

However with newer cards,  I am still able to retrieve PSE for the card, but I am getting either tag lost or transceive failed when selecting applet AID and sending GPO. I have tried increasing the timeout time as well. If anyone can help provide me some insights that would be very much appreciated.

**Code for selecting applet:**

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    IsoDep isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag);

                final byte[] TEST = {
                (byte) 0x00, 
                (byte) 0xA4, 
                (byte) 0x04, 
                (byte) 0x00,
                (byte) 0x07,
                (byte) 0xA0,  (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x03,
                (byte) 0x10,(byte) 0x10,
                (byte) 0x00,
        };



        try {
            isoDep.connect();
            isoDep.setTimeout(10000);
            byte[] result = isoDep.transceive(TEST);
            Log.i("test", "TEST: " + "transceived");
            String str = bytesToHex(result);

            Log.i("test", "TEST: " + str);

            Log.i("test", "TEST: " + "close");
            isoDep.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String error = e.getMessage();
            Log.i("test", "TEST: " + e);
            Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


}
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you post one complete set of logs from start till end without editing

Comment: @libemv.so.1.0.1 Sorry I am still new to this, but the only logs i have are those from android logcat which doesnt have much information on NFC. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: There is no difference between old and new cards in terms of commands. The reading and writing will happen so quick that in an ideal scenario the SELECT till final READ should happen in less than 500ms. I would suggest to increase the logging on your application and check more closely. You can either use Log.d(  or System.out.println( to log information in Logcat.

Comment: @libemv.so.1.0.1 Thank you will try to increase logging to find out. The reason i suspect something was different is because when i put in wrong parameters it sends me the correct error codes, and when i put in wrong lengths, i get the appropriate error codes as well. But when i put in the correct commands I get tag lost or transceived failed. Just thought that there was some sort of authentication feature that I am not aware about. Another thing is the newer card has its own unique ID while the older one doesnt, not sure if that is something I need to include?

Comment: yes confusing indeed. even though you said it is working for old cards, just asking out of curiosity - for testing are you firing the gpo alone(without a successful select in the same session?).

Comment: @libemv.so.1.0.1 I have tried both in the same session as well as alone. Still doesnt work.

Comment: Actually i think i somehow made the card unusable now. Cant be read by any card reader anymore. Will retest when i get my replacement card.

Comment: have you tried on some other reader? apart from select other commands cannot be tried alone.

Comment: @libemv.so.1.0.1 Not sure what I did but i think my card is not responding to any contactless reader. Tried using it with a chinese paywave card reader and in a couple of different stores but wouldnt work. Maybe I damaged something when i was trying various GPO commands.

Comment: With NFC you should read the PPSE not PSE